# Extension to generate Javadoc file in Visual Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, javadoc

I want to create a documentation file of my code. I've added the Javadoc comment in every public method I have. If I use other IDE, probably there is a menu to generate it, but unfortunately I use Visual Code.

Is there a way to generate Javadoc file in Visual Code? I only find one extension, with 2 thousands downloads but its not working. The name is [Javadoc-Generator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KeeganBruer.javadoc-generator)

I have tried to run using javadoc command in terminal, but it is not recognized. Do I need to install additional file?

Comment: do you want this extension ?[javadoc-tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=madhavd1.javadoc-tools)

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT is that working and able to generate the document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well firstly thanks for the good question and now i'm going to try to help you with your problem. I searched for an plug in of Javadoc for Visual Studio which is [Javadoc Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=madhavd1.javadoc-tools) with this plug in you can create coments just selecting where you want to make the comments, also you can export your comments and the best thing it's free. I tried this for one of my programmes and it works for me. Definitly i recommend you this, try it and i hope i helped you with your problem.

[Selecting where i want to create the comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2n1c.png)

[Final result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvebT.png)

Answer (score 0):

For Javadoc-Generator. In the documentation state "This generator will use the Javadoc located in the JDK referenced in your JAVA_HOME." Make sure you have `JAVA_HOME` set in your Environment Variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this worked for me, an extension [click here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=madhavd1.javadoc-tools) for Visual Studio which is Javadoc Tools and it's free.

This extension allows user to generate javadoc comments for all methods within a class. Below commands are available for use -

**Javadoc Tools: Export Javadoc** - This command allows you to export your Javadoc. The command should be executed in a Workspace(Multi-root workspaces supported as of version 1.6.0

**Javadoc Tools: Generate Javadoc Comments for Open File**- Only generates Javadoc Comments for the open File in focus

**Javadoc Tools: Generate Javadoc Comments for Workspace** - Generates Javadoc for all classes within the workspace. The files will be opened in the editor and the javadoc comments will be added. This command will not autosave the modified Files.

**Generate Javadoc Comments** -  Generates Javadoc Comments for the selected class.

Comment: [/help/referencing](/help/referencing)